# Как отредактировать данные запроса с помощью инструментов Firefox?

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, firefox-devtools

Мне нужно отредактировать передаваемые данные в запросе с помощью инструментов Firefox.
Но отредактировать я могу только ключи, а значение к ключам передаются как пустая строка.

ВОПРОС: **как мне передать ключи вместе с значениями?**

*Пожайлуста, не отвечайте что это можно сделать с помощью Postman, мне нужно это сделать без него.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что это изменит? Во вкладке сеть - уже отработанные данные.

Comment: какие ключи? какие значения? вы о чем? вы можете русскими словами сказать, то есть без терминов, значений которых вы не понимаете?